# Angular js-Web page freezes after form submitted

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a project I'm doing to learn Angular JS. It's a single page web application that allows to log contacts and edit them. For some reason that I can't figure out, my web page freezes any time I post data to Firebase. Can anyone help with this?

This my javascript file

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myContacts.contacts', ['ngRoute','firebase'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/contacts', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts/contacts.html',
    controller: 'contactsCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('contactsCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    $scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(ref);
    //console.log($scope.contacts);
    $scope.showAddForm = function(){
        $scope.addFormShow = true;
    }
    
    $scope.hide = function(){
        $scope.addFormShow = false;
    }
    
    $scope.addFormSubmit = function(){
       console.log('adding contact');
        
        //Assign values
        if($scope.name){var name = $scope.name}else {name=null;}
        if($scope.email){var email = $scope.email}else {email=null;}
        if($scope.company){var company = $scope.company}else {company=null;}
        if($scope.mobile_phone){var mobile_phone = $scope.mobile_phone}else { mobile_phone=null;}
        if($scope.home_phone){var home_phone = $scope.home_phone}else {home_phone=null;}
        if($scope.work_phone){var work_phone = $scope.work_phone}else {work_phone=null;}
        if($scope.street_address){var street_address = $scope.street_address}else {street_address=null;}
        if($scope.city){var city = $scope.city}else {city=null;}
        if($scope.province){var province = $scope.province}else {province=null;}
        if($scope.postal_code){var postal_code = $scope.postal_code}else {postal_code=null;}
        
        //Build Object
        $scope.contacts.$add({
            name:name,
            email:email,
            company:company,
            phone:[
                {
                    mobile:mobile_phone,
                    home:home_phone,
                    work:work_phone
                }   
            ],
            address:[
                {
                    street_address:street_address,
                    city: city,
                    province: province,
                    postal_code: postal_code
                }
            ]                
        }).then(function(ref){
          var id = ref.key(); 
           console.log('added contact with id: '+ id);
            //clear form
            clearFields();
            hide form
            $scope.addFormShow = false;
            
            //send message
            $scope.msg ="contact Added";
        });
        
    }
    
    //Clear $scope Fields
       function clearFields(){
        console.log('Clearing All Fields');
        $scope.name = '';
         $scope.email = '';
         $scope.company = '';
         $scope.mobile_phone = '';
         $scope.home_phone = '';
         $scope.work_phone = '';
         $scope.street_address = '';
         $scope.city = '';
         $scope.province = '';
         $scope.postal_code = '';
    }
    
    
}]);
```

and here is the HTML file

```html
<div class="row" ng-controller="contactsCtrl">
    <div class="large-10 columns">
        <!--<div data-alert ng-show="msg" class="alert-box">{{msg}}</div>-->
    <form ng-submit="addFormSubmit()" ng-show="addFormShow">
        <h3>Add Contact</h3>
        <!--Add Form-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>Name:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Contact Name" required/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>Email:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="email" placeholder="Contact Email" required/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>Company:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="company" placeholder="Company Name"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>Work Phone:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="work_phone" placeholder="Work Phone"/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>Mobile Phone:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="mobile_phone" placeholder="Mobile Phone" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>Home Phone:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="home_phone" placeholder="Mobile Phone"/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>Street Address:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="street_address" placeholder="Street Name"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>City:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="city" placeholder="City"/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>Province:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="state" placeholder="Province"/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <label>Postal Code:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="postal_code" placeholder="Postal Code"/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">    
                <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" class="button"/> 
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <h3>Your Contacts (3)</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="200px">Name</th>
                    <th width="200px">Company</th>
                    <th width="25%">Email</th>
                    <th width="25%">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                    <td><a href="#">{{contact.name}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{contact.company}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                    <td><a class="button tiny" ng-click="showEditForm(contact)">Edit</a><a class="button tiny alert" ng-click="removeContact(contact)">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-2 columns">
            <a class="button large" ng-click="showAddForm()" ng-hide="addFormShow">+</a>
            <a class="button large" ng-click="hide()" ng-show="addFormShow">-</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While checking your code I have the feeling that you are probably not initializing the firebase module.

So you should do it first

> Config firebase.initializeApp() or it will not work

```
  .config(function () {
        var config = {
              apiKey: "",
              authDomain: "",
              databaseURL: "",
              storageBucket: "",
              messagingSenderId: ""
            };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    });
```

Check this example, please use your own firebase initialization info to make it work I made your code work on muy test.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/moplin/zLozccap/

[image]